# Function not repeating everytime I click forward arrow

Tags: javascript

I have a function at the moment that makes it so every time I click the forward arrow the week moves forward 1 week.

JS

// Week dates - below the function that makes my dates display from the 3rd of Feb

```
let d = new Date(2020,1,3)
var dayElement = document.createElement("div");
dayElement.innerHTML = d.toLocaleDateString() + "-"
document.getElementById("month-today").appendChild(dayElement)

let nd = new Date(d)
nd.setDate(nd.getDate() + 6)

document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = nd.toLocaleDateString()
```

// Arrow forward - below the function that makes week move forward to next week

```
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", next)
function next() {

  let ndPlus = new Date(d)
  ndPlus.setDate(ndPlus.getDate() + 7)

  document.getElementById("month-today").innerHTML = ndPlus.toLocaleDateString() +  "-"

  let ndPlusWeek = new Date(2020,1,9)
  ndPlusWeek.setDate(ndPlusWeek.getDate() + 7)


  document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = ndPlusWeek.toLocaleDateString()
}
```

Every time I click the arrow forward the weeks should carry on moving 7 days but week only moves forward once.

Help?

Comment: in the second piece of code, the `ndPlus` var is set with the date of `d` var, created with 03/01/2020 before. that always will be third of january as a start...

Comment: It is clear that the code you shown misses some important parts for us to detect the error. I think you are updating the `d` variable somewhere. Besides, your `next` function did not close. Please give as much relevant detail as possible.

Comment: thanks @Pierre. So how can I make it so it adds 7 days to the current date? The reason why I have done the 03/02 is because this week starts on the 03/02.

Comment: @HamdiDouss not updating d anywhere. have closed the function now

Comment: @Rpx are you sure your function works twice? If you are not updating `d` anywhere, it should only work once. After that you will get always get 01/10 (in month-today) and 01/16(in month-seven)

Comment: @HamdiDouss thanks for bringing to my attention. Actually you are right only moves forward 1 week. Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick fix, even if it is not elegant:

```
function next() {

  let ndPlus = new Date(d);
  ndPlus.setDate(ndPlus.getDate() + 7)
  d = ndPlus;

  document.getElementById("month-today").innerHTML = ndPlus.toLocaleDateString() +  "-"

  let ndPlusWeek = new Date(ndPlus)
  ndPlusWeek.setDate(ndPlus.getDate() + 6)


  document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = ndPlusWeek.toLocaleDateString()
}
```

Comment: Tried this - gets to the week of 02/03 and displays 02/03/2020-
08/02/2020 so reverts back to February month.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the original Date variable to the newly changed date so that you can add more days.

```
  let ndPlus = new Date(d)
  ndPlus.setDate(ndPlus.getDate() + 7)

  document.getElementById("month-today").innerHTML = ndPlus.toLocaleDateString() +  "-"

  let ndPlusWeek = new Date(2020,1,9)
  ndPlusWeek.setDate(ndPlusWeek.getDate() + 7)


  document.getElementById("month-seven").innerHTML = ndPlusWeek.toLocaleDateString()

  d = ndPlus
}
```